# Escape a double quote with a double quote

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I’m trying to get csv writer to use a double quote as an escape character and add a double quote to a double quote if it appears in the data field.

My function is part of an Apache Beam Dataflow job.

Any advice would be appreciated.

The input record:
"ab"c","def"

The actual output my function returns:
abc", def

The output I’m trying to achieve
"abc""", def

The input file may contain records like this:

1, "mystring1","mystring2"
2, "mystring3","mystring4"
3, "myst"ring5","mystring6"

Notice record 3 has a double quote in the field.

I would like to escape that double quote by adding
a double quote before it then quote the entire field.

1, mystring1,mystring2
2, mystring3,mystring4
3, "myst""ring5",mystring6

The function I’m calling

```
def parse_file(element):
      for line in csv.reader([element], quotechar='"', delimiter=','):
          output_str = io.StringIO()
          cw = csv.writer(output_str, quotechar='"', delimiter=',', escapechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
          cw.writerow(line)
          output_str.close()
          clean_line = ', '.join(line)
          return clean_line
```

Comment: you can use '\' to escape

Comment: Why do you have 5/6 of a non-breaking space entity in your code?

Comment: Hi Tasnuva I need to use a doble quote as the output is a file that is to be loaded into BigQuery.

Comment: To clarify better you should add some more input examples and the expected output

Comment: Hi @NoahResch I have added a few more examples, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution which takes the input element of type string.

```
vec = str('"ab"c","def""')
print(list(map(lambda x: '"' + x + '"' if '""' in x else x, [y.strip('"').replace('"', '""') for y in vec.split(',')])))
```

If i understood something wong I apologies